# AppKit thread-safe or not?

Tags: cocoa, appkit

Can you explain me is AppKit thread-safe or not? Where can I read about it? (Except Threaded Programming Guide because this documentation creates more question instead answers). For example can I validateVisibleItems of NSToolbar in separated thread? Or can I increment value of NSProgressIndicator in second thread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not in general.  You [should not send messages to any UI objects except from the main thread](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/AboutThreads/AboutThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH6-SW21).

In the specific example you give, you can use [performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBEHAEF) to get around the restriction:

```
[myToolbar performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(validateVisibleItems) 
                            withObject: nil
                         waitUntilDone: whatever];
```